# Execute :hover and :hover:after animation with keyframes on component load

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, css-transitions

i would like to play this hover animation on component load, because I wrote a JS function that checks if the component is in the viewport and reloads it (changes its class).
You can use Sass (scss) or regular css.

```scss
.module .active {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--text-color-dark);
  animation: loadInAnimation ease 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes loadInAnimation { // add :hover and :hover:after event
  0% {
    // start of animation
  }

  100% {
    // end ofanimation
  }
}

.module .active:after { // transform into keyframe animation
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.module .active:hover:after { // transform into keyframe animation
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

JS (irrelevant):

```js
    <script>
      function reveal() {
        var reveals = document.querySelectorAll(".reveal");
        console.log(reveals);
      
        for (var i = 0; i < reveals.length; i++) {
          var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
          var elementTop = reveals[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
          var elementVisible = 150;
        
          if (elementTop < windowHeight - elementVisible) {
            reveals[i].classList.add("active");
          } else {
            reveals[i].classList.remove("active");
          }
        }
      }
      
      window.addEventListener("scroll", reveal);
      window.addEventListener("load", reveal);
    </script>
```

HTML (also irrelevant):

```html
<h2 className='heading reveal'>Tennisakademie Vasquez</h2>
```

Comment: I've checked that the js code and the html code works on hover. This question is only about css animations and transitions

Comment: Yes, thats why I would like to transform the :hover event into an animation on component load

Comment: Don't you need to add the animation to the pseudo element rather than the element itself? And how long do you want the effect to last when you are implementing it onload rather than on a hover? i.e. when does the effect get removed?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comment. I've fixed the animation with an additional element providing the :after feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the animation with an additional element providing the :after feature:

```css
.module .heading {
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: var(--text-color-dark);
}

.module .active {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: var(--text-color-dark);
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  .reveal-line {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-out;
    animation: loadInAnimation ease 1.5s;
  }
}

@keyframes loadInAnimation {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }

  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```
<h3 className='heading reveal'>Unsere Angebote<div className='reveal-line' /></h3>
```